# How to customize the <title> tag

Tags: theming

I have downloaded nexus free theme and I want to change the title
in all pages of my site.

Is there a way to do it editing the template.php?

thanks...

Answer (score 3):

If you using D7 and not D8, take a look at [page_title](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_title) module. I just googled it for you.

> The word "title" is a bit overloaded. Every piece of content in Drupal
>   has a title, and so does every page. The page title is the one found
>   in the HTML head inside the  tag. It is also used on SERPs
>   (Search Engine Result Pages) and can greatly enhance your websites SEO
>   (Search Engine Optimization).
>
> This module gives you granular control over the page title. You can
>   specify patterns for how the title should be structured and, on
>   content creation pages, specify the page title separately to the
>   content's title.